# Is there a way to populate two or more different UITableViews using the same cellForRowAtIndexPath function?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a custom UITableView class that I have multiple instances of in a single ViewController. What is the most elegant way to populate these different instances with unique cell data? Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer I wrote here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19568737/480415

May help you achieve this.:

> You could also put 2 separate UITableViews on your UIViewController,
>   then handle it in the delegates/datasource methods, ie:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(tableView == _leftTableView)
    {
         static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
         UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

         if (cell == nil) {
             cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
         }

         //fill cell data here

         return cell;
    }
    else if(tableView == _rightTableView)
    {
         static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
         UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

         if (cell == nil) {
             cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
         }    

         //fill cell data here

         return cell;
     }
     return nil;
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, I guess I didn't know the actual name of the tableView is passed in to the function, not just its class. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Right now I can think of two possible solutions:

1. Have different table view data sources for each table. You can create the data sources in the same file as the view controller if that is important to you.
2. Have your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method conditionally load the cells depending on the table. You can find out which table view is calling the method with the first argument of the method. You could also use the `tag` property of UITableView for differentiation.

I personally prefer the first one.

Comment: how would you go about creating multiple data sources in the same file?

Comment: You can have several classes in the same file, declaring more than one interface in the .h file (.m is also possible for private classes), and writing the implementations in the .m file.

Some people advice against this, but I believe it might be acceptable in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that the method signature `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` includes a reference to the tableView.  You can use that to determine which tableView is requesting a cell, and return the same/different data accordingly.

Comment: If I'm working with two tables views of the same class, would I still be able to differentiate them this way? Or should I always make a new class for every different table I create?

Comment: The `tableView` parameter references an instance, not a class, so you would always be able to differentiate two table views.

Answer (score 0):

in your controller, you should have your tableViews defined as a properties

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITableView *myTableView
```

Then, in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` you can check which table is making the callback using something like:

```
if (tableView == self.myTableView){
    //return cell
} else if (tableView == someOtherTableView) {
    //return some other cell
}
```